# toggle class for the clicked element queryselectorAll

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to expand a div `onclick` the problem is it expands every other div with the same class

```
<div class="formations div">
          <div class="buttn" @click="expand">
              <p>Formations</p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="link">
              <a>link</a>
              <a>link</a>
              <a>link</a>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="Evolution div">
          <div class="buttn">
              <p>Evolution & Carrieres</p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
          </div>
          <div class="link">
              <a>link</a>
              <a>link</a>
              <a>link</a>
          </div>
      </div>
```

js:

```
expand(){
        let links= document.querySelectorAll(".link")
        for(let i = 0; i< links.length; i++){
            links[i].classList.toggle('show');
        }
```

I tried other solutions but i couldn't fix the issue

Comment: do you want to get the first or second .link div

Comment: First of all, I'd use a more descriptive class name than "div", but this is is typical. Find the closest ancestor to the button and the links, then use `querySelectorAll` from that node. Note that `Element`, in modern browsers, has a `closest` method just for this, so you can do `button.closest('.div').querySelectorAll('.link')`.

Comment: the first without adding show class to the second

Comment: there is actually more than two .link i just showed two of them, i'm planning to add expand function to all of them

Answer (score 1):

You can send button to function and toggle the closest links.

With Vue you can create data object with array of buttons and links, then method to toggle specific links, or you can use refs, without data and pass ref name to method:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    types : [
      { name : 'Formations',
        links: [ 'formations link1', 'formations link2', 'formations link3' ]
      },
      { name : 'Evolution & Carrieres',
        links: [ 'evolution link1', 'evolution link2', 'evolution link3' ]
      },
    ],
    toggleLinks: { el: null, state: false }
  },
  methods: {
    expand(el) {
      this.toggleLinks.el = el.name;
      this.toggleLinks.state = !this.toggleLinks.state;
    },
    expandRef(el) {
      let links = this.$refs[el].closest('.div').querySelectorAll('.link')
      links.forEach(l => l.classList.toggle('show'))
    }
  },
})

/*function expand(el) {
  let links = el.closest('.div').querySelectorAll('.link')
  links.forEach(l => l.classList.toggle('show'))
}*/
```

```css
.link {
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#app {
  display: flex;
  
}
.refs {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul >
    <h3>With data</h3>
    <li v-for="type in types" :key="type.name">
      <button class="buttn" @click="expand(type)">
        <p>{{ type.name }}</p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
      </button>
      <ul class="link" :class="{ 'show': toggleLinks.state && toggleLinks.el === type.name }">
        <li v-for="link in type.links" :key="link">
          <a>{{ link }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="refs">
    <h3>With refs</h3>
    <div class="formations div">
        <button ref="f" class="buttn" @click="expandRef('f')">
            <p>Formations</p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="link">
            <a>formations link</a>
            <a>formations link</a>
            <a>formations link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Evolution div">
        <button ref="e" class="buttn" @click="expandRef('e')">
            <p>Evolution & Carrieres</p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="link">
            <a>evolution link</a>
            <a>evolution link</a>
            <a>evolution link</a>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<!-- <div class="formations div">
    <button class="buttn" onclick="expand(this)">
        <p>Formations</p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="link">
        <a>formations link</a>
        <a>formations link</a>
        <a>formations link</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="Evolution div">
    <button class="buttn" onclick="expand(this)">
        <p>Evolution & Carrieres</p><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="link">
        <a>evolution link</a>
        <a>evolution link</a>
        <a>evolution link</a>
    </div>
</div> -->
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'closest' of null

Comment: Like you see in answer there is no errors, are you using plain js or vue?

Comment: i'm using vue, is there a diffrence?